# Django models ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-1.7

This is django1.7 code for database model
I have problem with this code. 
This is models.py file.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    person_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    person_family=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    person_father=models.ForeignKey('Person')
    person_mother=models.ForeignKey('Person')
```

Error :

[image: error]

If I remove one of this -> 'person_mother or person_father '
Errors will be disappear.
But when both of them are in code error will happen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the HINT you get when you run migrate (or try running validate): You need to add a `related_name` kwarg to your `ForeignKey`, something like this:

`person_father=models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='child_from_father')
person_mother=models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name='child_from_mother')`

You need to use `related_name` because when Django encounters a `ForeignKey` it will try to add a *reverse relation* field in the foreign key model. For example, if you have an `Author` model and a `Book` model that has a `ForeignKey` to `Author`, django will add a `book_set` reverse relation manager attribute to `Author` (to query all `Books` of a particular `Author`).

Now, in your case, Django wanted to add a `person_set` to `Person`, however, because you have two `ForeignKeys` to `Person` it doesn't know how to name the reverse relation manager attributes. That's why it hints you to use `related_name`. So, using the `person_father` attribute will get you a queryset of the fathers of a person and `person_mother` the same for mothers.

Comment: Your related names are quite confusing. These related names represent "children", so maybe "child_from_father" and "child_from_mother"

Comment: Also, you are using the exact name of the field. That shouldn't pass model checks

Comment: @Alvaro probably you are right... I've changed them

Comment: Agreed - most of the times I like to use the same name for both the field name and the related_name. However this won't work in this case (since the ForeignKey is to *the same* model)

Comment: nice ! another question : from where u have this exact knowledge about django ? i mean something like this question !?

Comment: Django has a really great documentation, so reading it is the *best* way to learn it. Just go to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/ and start reading *everything*... For example, the stuff I mentioned about related_name are in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name